# JPGraph PHP chart

Tags: php, arrays, charts, jpgraph

I want to create a pie chart using JPgraph. in a php file i've two arrays as a result of some process. using JPgraph, i want to plot these 2 arrays in a pie chart. one array consist of the percentage value and the other consist of the value name.

i can't plot the arrays into chart in the same php file(i wrote chart code in the same php file as the process).

my scenario is like this:
first page is the chart, there will be hyperlink to open dialog which contained with arrays results in table. How would i do this while i can't write chart code in the same php file as the process code that generates arrays?

Wow, i hope i made my question clear. Thank you very much :)

Comment: form jpgraph manual, i can  use POST to pass large amount of parameter(such as array). At the moment, i  use GET method to do this. Using implode, i change array into string then pass the string into another php file. maybe, there will be problem if the string is too big. since GET method can't handle more than 4k data (as i know from google search)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either pass the data in the URL via an IMG tag, or pass a reference to where the script can find the data in the URL (e.g. dump it in a temp file and pass the path)

Comment: Yes, img tag works, passing the parameter via URL. Thank you.